# (Hector Slam)catkin_make error on raspberry pi3, very slow compiling

Tags: ros, slam, compile, ros-kinetic, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there , I trying to install hector slam package on raspberry pi3 (ubuntu mate)

I installed hector slam package through git clone command

But the error generated when I compiled it. (scanning dependencies of target)

the phenomenon is that compiling speed was very slow (almost stop)

How can i solve this problem??  I have to implement hector mapping on raspberry pi3.  please answers..

Someone told me to install through apt-get (It does not require compilation  <- right?)

I'm sorry my grammer T.T

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289487/(hector-slam)catkin_make-error-on-raspberry-pi3,-very-slow-compiling/) by [DongHyeong Kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/34513/donghyeong-kang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu Mate has a lot of overhead. Try the Raspberry Pi distribution from downloads.ubiquityrobotics.com.  If you have trouble compiling with a default catkin_make, use the -j1 parameter, it takes longer but may work if the default -j4 fails.

---

Originally posted by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) with karma: 147 on 2018-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on 2019-11-02**:
HOw can I change -j4 to -j1?